# Getting computers serialnumber

Tags: windows, active-directory, operating-system, sccm, system-administration

I have 88+ PC that I want to report their serial numbers along with their computer name, I have Bitdefender console that doesnt show serial number,

Tried to use this command on DC with no luck, (Get-ADComputer -Filter *).Name | Foreach-Object {Get-CimInstance Win32_Bios -ComputerName $_ -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object @{n='Computername'; e={$_.PSComputerName}},SerialNumber}

is there anyway to get computers serial number on the DC active directory?

Comment: Please check this if may helpful : https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3820fa49-a66c-462e-99bb-d61c36b7d31e/search-serialnumber-attribute-of-computer-object-in-ad?forum=winserverDS

Comment: You are using lot's of tags here, so a quick question. Do you already use SCCM? Because if so this would be part of HW Inventory so you already have all the info. Problem with actively querying like this would always be that offline devices can not be reached. But with access to the SCCM db you can just run a quick query there. Is this an option for you?

Comment: hello,  I never used SCCM before, what would be the simplest way to deploy and extract information that I need ? can the SCCM provide me with HW specs, like RAM, Processor ,etc ?

Answer (score 1):

I tried with your PowerShell script only getting the serialNumber of local computer

[image]

The serialNumber attribute exists in AD. Most likely, it has no value for any computers. The wmic command retrieves the serial Number property from the BIOS class of WMI for the local computer.

Even I tried the suggestion provided in this [document](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3820fa49-a66c-462e-99bb-d61c36b7d31e/search-serialnumber-attribute-of-computer-object-in-ad?forum=winserverDS) using ADFIND command but ADFIND support only 2008 window server as I can not create 2008 supported seems it is no longer available in azure.

Would suggest you Check the script on the article it can help you.

https://deployhappiness.com/find-serial-numbers-in-active-directory/

Also you can easily find all serials with SCCM.(if you have)

Reference : [Serial number attribute of computer object](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/0c473196-afd0-43ec-b812-db54d62c2b16/serial-number-attribute-of-computer-object?forum=winserverDS)

Comment: Thanks for your replies, I dont know if we can go with SCCM options, do you have any recommendations for SCCM ? does it work wiht SQL Server Express ? please do let me know if anything comes to your mind !

Answer (score 0):

Try the command below, it should work:

`Get-ADComputer -Filter *| Select-Object Name | Foreach-Object {Get-CimInstance Win32_Bios -ComputerName $_.Name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object PSComputerName,SerialNumber}`